# Multiple projects in Android Studio

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio, dependencies, project-structure

I've been using eclipse for a couple of years now but have finally decided to move to Android Studio. The problem is that during these years I've created over 100 apps that are based on one project.

The apps are more or less the same, they import the main library and they differ in graphics and a raw data file. That way I could work on the main library and just click export on the project I wanted to update. But Android Studio doesn't seem to have the same structure as eclipse.

Is it possible to have the library as a module and all the other projects as other modules being dependent on the library module and then export each module separate? Or do I have to create a different project for each "app"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Android Studio comes with new build system: Gradle(while Eclipse uses Ant). Gradle allows you to create `project flavours`. This means that you can create multiple builds with different package names and source sets. Take a look here: http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/studio-build.html

So basically, you can have only one project and multiple project flavours, which have different packages, resource and even different source code where you need it.

Comment: I've been using Eclipse for quite a while and when I try to import my workspace which basically contains a good 100 APKs, I end-up with one single project/module and it just fails to build anything. However Android Studio is supposed to setup one module per project considering they are not just flavor, which can be manually created, but then I end-up using AS without gradle! Sadly it now creates APK 3 times the original size and I don't even have the option to export/build a release APK.